# Get SQL Server 2000 instance path using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2000, instance

I need to relocate files to SQL Server 2000 default data folder programmatically using C#, I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Given below link only works for SQL Server 2005 and above versions.
[C# How to get SQL Server installation path programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165576/c-sharp-how-to-get-sql-server-installation-path-programatically)

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The "supported" way to do this would be to use DMO. The property you want is called [SQLDataRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134029.aspx):</strike>

> The **SQLDataRoot** property identifies the default operating-system directory implementing storage for Microsoft SQL Server system user-defined databases.

The root of the DMO documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133993.aspx)

In fact, [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162557.aspx) (that was released with SQL Server 2005) supports connecting to SQL Server 2000, so you should use SMO for this task. The property you want there is, I believe, [DefaultFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.defaultfile.aspx)

This has the benefit that the same code should work against 2000,2005,2008 and 2008 R2 instances.

Comment: the problem here is how am i supposed to relocate without path.