# How to convert certain C# code to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I've been googling around around and read this article

[C# How to get SQL Server installation path programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165576/c-sharp-how-to-get-sql-server-installation-path-programatically)

and this is exactly what i need in VB.NET , however i'm not good in translating this code into VB.NET Code. So, any help would greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Note : I'm using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Basic 2008

Comment: Well,then you should look at something like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question was originally titled about retrieving SQL Server's installation path, I felt it was more about a code translation problem (the solution already existed, just not in the right language).

But then I thought that the method in the original code was fairly blunt.

Evan provided you with what I assume is a workable translation of the existing solution. But probably a much easier way to perform this specific task - assuming you just need to find the installation path for an instance you're already connected to, and assuming that a user who can read the registry will also have `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions - is to issue this simple query against [the DMV `sys.dm_os_loaded_modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179907%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) from your program:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM sys.dm_os_loaded_modules
  WHERE name LIKE '%sqlservr.exe';
```

This will give you something like this:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe

You have some parsing to do, depending on exactly what you're after (e.g. do you want to stop at `MSSQL`, or `Binn`?), but this is much easier than reading the registry or other methods that are out there IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I just used a code converter ... There are only basic things that need to be changed ..

```
Using sqlServerKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server")
    For Each subKeyName As String In sqlServerKey.GetSubKeyNames()
        If subKeyName.StartsWith("MSSQL.") Then
            Using instanceKey As RegistryKey = sqlServerKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName)
                Dim instanceName As String = instanceKey.GetValue("").ToString()

                If instanceName = "MSSQLSERVER" Then
                    'say
                    Dim path__1 As String = instanceKey.OpenSubKey("Setup").GetValue("SQLBinRoot").ToString()
                    path__1 = Path.Combine(path__1, "sqlserver.exe")
                    Return path__1
                End If
            End Using
        End If
    Next
End Using
```

If you were to just read a quick article on C#, you would notice that strings are declared differently, and minor syntax discrepancies exist such as `foreach` vs `for each`

You can read [here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) for some more common differences.

Answer (score 1):

I use a very good (***offline***) tool, called **[Convert .NET Free](http://www.fishcodelib.com/Convert.htm)**

It's from [www.fishcodelib.com](http://www.fishcodelib.com/)

Here's a direct link to the latest release (as of 19/04/14) **Size:** 2.06MB, **File**: Zip :

[[Direct Link]](http://www.fishcodelib.com/files/ConvertNet2.zip)

Hope this is of some use ;)

P.S. This software requires **.NET Framework 4.5**.

Answer (score 0):

This almost never fails! :) Good Luck

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/